# Keep checkbox checked when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html

We wanted to have a dark mode on our page. I have managed to make a darkmode slider but I want it to keep on dark mode if you refresh or go to the next page.

JS

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>
```

Checkbox

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" onclick="myFunction()" />
       <label class="label" for="chk">
         <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
         <div class="ball"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than having a toggle that you have to manually switch maybe use [prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)?

Answer (score 3):

You can keep some of user preferences in `localStorage`. If you are new and your goal is to understand how to do exactly what you ask for, this is one of the ways of doing it.

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a simple key->value storage, where you can store data that belongs to [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin) even across browser sessions.

So, what you can do is:

1.Create a function, that looks on `'colorMode'` into `localStorage` and sets your color scheme according to that.

```
function colorModeSwitch () {
  const mode = localStorage['colorMode']
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode', mode)
}
```

2.Find your checkbox, set it according `'colorMode'` property too.

```
const checkbox         = document.querySelector('#chk')
      checkbox.checked = localStorage['colorMode']
```

3.`addEventListener` to your checkbox that saves state of that checkbox to `localStorage` and changes your color scheme by calling a function from p.1

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  localStorage['colorMode'] = checkbox.checked || ""
  colorModeSwitch()
})
```

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .dark-mode {
      background-color: #222222;
    }
    .contents {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
  <title>0_0</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk"/>
  <label class="label" for="chk">Dark Mode Checkbox</label>
  <div class="contents">Im in dark mode now!</div>
</body>
<script>
  function colorModeSwitch () {
    const mode = localStorage['colorMode']
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode', mode)
  }

  const checkbox         = document.querySelector('#chk')
        checkbox.checked = localStorage['colorMode']

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    localStorage['colorMode'] = checkbox.checked || ""
    colorModeSwitch()
  })

  colorModeSwitch()
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: this is nice, i put it in my html and i can turn the darkmode on, but i cannot switch back. i get this error message Cannot set property 'checked' of null at the line: checkbox.checked = localStorage['colorMode']

Comment: Your javascript code is probably somewhere in `head` html block, so that `checkbox` is not exists yet. In my example I put js code below the `body` so all html elements already present on the page. I did it just to keep it simple, so if you want to put your code in `head`, then try to wrap it around `window.onload = function { ...code... }` or smtn like that.

Comment: ahhh now i get it! thanks! its working now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the user's preference in the client and read it from there in your JS code.

Assuming that your body element starts in light mode:

JS

```js
function myFunction(e) {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

   if (e.target.checked) {
     localStorage.setItem('dark', 1)
   } else {
     localStorage.removeItem('dark')
   }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const isDark = localStorage.getItem('dark')
  if (isDark) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-mode')
  }
}
```